# sum of binomial distributions

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have the following real life problem to solve, about the use of a scarce resource. I'll explain it with an example, as I am a physician and not a mathematician, but I hope to find help.
Suppose we have 4 urns (A B C D) containing red and blue marbles

- The urn A contains 2 red marbles out of 100 marbles (2 red and 98
  blue)
- The urn B contains 5 red marbles out of 100 marbles (5 red and    95
  blue)
- The urn C contains 12 red marbles out of 100 marbles (12 red    and
  88 blue)
- The urn D contains 30 red marbles out of 100 marbles (30    red and
  70 blue)

If I randomly select 5 marbles from the urn A, 2 marbles from the urn B, 4 marbles from the urn C, and 1 from the urn D (all in a raw, with replacement)

- what is the probability of the event: getting a red marble?

  (I don’t know what formula or model should I use. I think I could use binomial distribution if only one urn was present I think multinomial distribution is not for this case. Any suggestion?).Thank you

Comment: Do you mean "getting *exactly* one red marble" or "getting *at least* one red marble"? If the latter, then note that the complementary event is "getting no red marble," which is the same as "getting not red marble from any urn."

Comment: getting at least one red marble

Comment: Whoops, misread the question. :P

Comment: @nimbex Then compute the probability to get no red marble from urn $1$. Same for urn 2, urn 3, urn 4 (each of them using a Binomial distribution, for instance, if you take marbles from each urn *with replacement*); and multiply these 4 probabilities. By independence, this will give you the probability to get no red marble at all overall.

Comment: $100$ marbles, but $3$ red and $95$ blue in urn $B$? $95 + 3 \ne 100$

Comment: @ clement C  Thus it's 4 binomial distribution, then I multiply them. This should account for any possible combination, if I get it right. I will try immediately with that. Thank you

Comment: @ Niknarf Right, it's almost midnight here. It seems I am not able to sum 3 and 5 right now.

Comment: Please note that (at least the way I understand it), we don't have binomial distributions here, but hypergeometric distributions.

Comment: @nimbex Haha! No problem. I made sure to explain everything thoroughly in my solution for you.

Comment: @ Mau314 sorry I did not specify that the selection was with replacement (as marbles are patients, and they have a predefined probability of being red i.e.: 2 out of 100)

Comment: @ nimbex: Oh, but then the solutions below refer to a different question as they assume $\mathrm{\textit{no replacement}}$!

Comment: @ Mau314 whops.. sorry I see the solution below refer to hypergeometric distributions, however I think I can solve it with binomial distribution, if I got right what was suggested

Comment: @ nimbex: Yes, it actually looks a little simpler; e.g. in Nilknarf's solution, we would now have $P_A^\ast=(98/100)^5$.

Comment: @ Mau314 thank you. Does it make any difference if I say that I don't want to extract them among 4 urns all in a raw, but I want to extract the at the same time among the 4 urns?

Comment: @ nimbex: The way you described the situation, no, it doesn't make a difference. The solutions use the facts that we can distinguish the four urns and that it's clear how many marbles we draw from each, but technically time plays no role.

Answer (score 1):

We can find the probability of not getting a red marble:
$$\left(\frac{98}{100}\right)\left(\frac{97}{99}\right)\left(\frac{96}{98}\right)\left(\frac{95}{97}\right)\left(\frac{94}{96}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{95}{100}\right)\left(\frac{94}{99}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{88}{100}\right)\left(\frac{87}{99}\right)\left(\frac{86}{98}\right)\left(\frac{85}{97}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{70}{100}\right)$$

Then subtract this value from one to get the probability of getting at least one red marble. I'll leave the computation to you.

Comment: Though this is for *without replacement* it is easy to adjust for the required *with replacement* case, where the probabilities for each consecutive draw *from the same urn* do not change.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: the probability of getting a red marble is $1-P^*$, where $P^*$ is the probability of *not* getting a red marble. When you draw $5$ times from urn $A$, the probability of getting no red marbles is
$$P^*_A=\frac{98}{100}*\frac{97}{99}*\frac{96}{98}*\frac{95}{97}*\frac{94}{96}$$
from urn $B$, the probability of getting no reds is
$$P^*_B=\frac{95}{100}*\frac{94}{99}$$
from urn $C$, it is
$$P^*_C=\frac{88}{100}*\frac{87}{99}*\frac{86}{98}*\frac{85}{97}$$
and from urn $D$, it is
$$P^*_D=\frac{70}{100}$$
Then the probability of getting *no* reds is
$$P^*=P^*_AP^*_BP^*_CP^*_D$$
and the probability of getting at least one red is
$$1-P^*$$